# How to compare datetime in same column in sql

Tags: mysql, t-sql, datetime

I'm currently developing a function where I needto compare two datetime in a same column and if two values are equal then I need to rank it 1. If the next datetime is greater than current, I need to increment the rank to 2 and so on. I don't want to use Ranking functions as i am facing some issues when I use ranking functions. I need to take time also into account while comparing the dates. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

**Table**

```
Date
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000
2015-01-01 13:09:00.000
2015-01-01 13:09:00.000
2015-01-01 13:09:00.000
```

**Desired Output**

```
Date                           Qnum
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000        1
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000        1
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000        1
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000        2
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000        2
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000        2
2015-01-01 13:09:00.000        3
2015-01-01 13:44:00.000        4
2015-01-01 13:44:00.000        4
```

Comment: Use a SEQUENCE then. Only call it when your adding numbers. But if you mean this to be like DENSE_RANK()...well, it gets pretty convoluted. Also, why does your rank not work? Can I see what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.

**Usage :** Select * from [dbo].usf_Rank

**How it works :** It builds a list of Dates in asc order and ranks them using an identity column while inserting into the helper table @Tbl in this manner :

1 D1

2 D2

3 D3

Then just inner join with the original table using the date column to expand and get the results as you wanted by returning a Table. (Using Table Valued Functions syntax )

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[usf_Rank]()
RETURNS @Results Table
(
    D1  Datetime ,
    RNK INT
)

AS
Begin

Declare @Tbl Table (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL , D1  Datetime )
Declare @Tbl2 Table ( D1  DAtetime)

-- INERT INTO @Tbl2 (D1) SELECT DATE_COLUMN FROM REAL_TABLE  -- I suppose this would be how you would actually use it instead of the fixed date values that I used for illustration below.
INSERT INTO @Tbl2 (D1)  Values 
('2012-07-09 00:00:00.000'),
('2012-07-09 00:00:00.000'),
('2012-07-09 00:00:00.000'),
('2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2015-01-01 13:44:00.000'),
('2015-01-01 13:44:00.000'),
('2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2015-01-01 13:44:00.000')

-- Generate the Rankings by using ID col which is identity column
insert into @Tbl select D1  from @Tbl2 group by D1 Order by D1

-- Expand by joining with orig table to get results in the format you want
insert into @Results
select t1.D1, t1.ID from @Tbl t1 inner join  @Tbl2 T2 ON T1.D1 = T2.D1

RETURN 
END 
Go
```